# Why isn't jQuery working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

So I am developing a slideout menu for my site using jQuery, and the whole thing works fine in Chrome, but it is not working in Internet Explorer. I am running IE11.  I have looked through numerous posts on this and have come to no solution.  Help is greatly appreciated.

```css
@charset "utf-8";



.navdiv{
 bottom:0px;
 top:0px;
 border-right: 50px solid #3184a1;
 wdith:1000px;
 position:fixed;
 left:-1040px;
 background-color:#67b5d1;
 z-index:1;
 box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 
}

 .navdiv:after
{
 position: absolute;
 content: ' ';
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 right: -70px;
 top: 50%;
 border-width: 15px 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent #3184a1;
 z-index:100;
}

ul
{
 width:1000px;
 z-index:2;
 postition:fixed;
}

li
{
 list-style-type: none; 
}

.menubutton 
{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 2;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-left: 16px;
 margin-top: 8px;
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px #222);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px #222);
 
}

.menuTable
{
 margin-top: 12px;
 margin-left: 116px;
 position:fixed;
 z-index:2;
 
 
}

.menubox
{
 width:360px;
 height:200px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:2; 
}


.Xbutton
{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 9px;
 margin-left: 1003px;
}

.navdiv, .spinningimage, .menubutton
{
 -webkit-transition: all 1200ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1200ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 1200ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 1200ms ease;
 transition: all 1200ms ease;
}

.menubutton, .Xbutton
{
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
 transition: all 300ms ease;
}


.spinningimage
{
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 4;
 margin-top: 168px;
 margin-left: -32px;
 
 -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="menuTest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    
    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#menubutton").click(function(){
    $("div").css({
 
 
 "left": "0px",
 
 
 
 });
});


$("#Xbutton").click(function(){
    $("div ").css({
 
 
 "left": "-1040px",
 
 
 
 });
});


});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".workbox").hover(function(){
 $(".spinningimage").css({
  
  "-ms-transform": "rotate(720deg)", /* IE 9 */
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(720deg)", /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    "transform": "rotate(720deg)"
 
 });
 });
  $(".workbox").mouseleave(function(){
 $(".spinningimage").css({
  
  "-ms-transform": "rotate(0deg)", /* IE 9 */
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(0deg)", /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    "transform": "rotate(0deg)"
 
 });
 });
 });
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".menubutton").hover(function() {
  $(this).css({
   
 "-webkit-filter": "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)",
  "filter": "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)"
   
 });
 });
  $(".menubutton").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css({
   
    "-webkit-filter": "drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px #222)",
  "filter": "drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px #222)"
   
 });
 });
 $(".Xbutton").hover(function() {
  $(this).css({
   
    "-webkit-filter": "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)",
  "filter": "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)"
   
   
 });  
 });
 $(".Xbutton").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css({
   
    "-webkit-filter": "drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px #222)",
  "filter": "drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px #222)"
   
   
 });  
 });
 $(".workbox").hover(function() {
  $(this).attr("src","DashedWorkBox.png");
   }, function() {
  $(this).attr("src","WorkBox.png");
 });
});

</script>

 

<div class="navdiv" id="navdiv">

 <img src="x button.png" class="Xbutton" id="Xbutton" width="30" height="30" alt=""/>
 <img src="MenuButton.png" class="menubutton" id="menubutton" width="30" height="30" alt=""/>
 <table width="200" border="0" class="menuTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="WorkBox.png" class="menubox workbox" width="474" height="278" alt=""/><img src="spinning_icon.png" class="spinningimage" alt=""/></td>
      <td><img src="Menu Box.png" class="menubox" width="474" height="278" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="Menu Box.png" class="menubox" width="474" height="278" alt=""/></td>
      <td><img src="Menu Box.png" class="menubox" width="474" height="278" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="Menu Box.png" class="menubox" width="474" height="278" alt=""/></td>
      <td><img src="Menu Box.png" class="menubox" width="474" height="278" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 
  <li>
  <ul></ul>

<ul></ul>
</li>

</div>







</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any clue in IE javascript console? (press F12 *I guess*)

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't working - and that you just aren't seeing the css results, because they are -webkit- ???

Comment: I've tried your code and it doesn't really work at all and you've misspelled width, and you're over engineering this. Simply add a class on click to the div you want to show, and use css transition for the animation. (Doesn't work in Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I created a very basic codepen based on your original code, simplifying your animating down to a click toggle and css transition (just animate the absolute position left from -300px, or whatever width, to 0 and it will then show and hide and should work in most browsers):

```js
$('.menu-icon').click(function(){
  $('.navdiv').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.navdiv{
 bottom: 0px;
 top:0px;
 border-right: 50px solid #3184a1;
 width: 300px;
 position: absolute;
 left: -300px;
 background-color:#67b5d1;
 box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 0;
  transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
  color: black;
}

.navdiv.open {
  left: 0px;
}

 .navdiv:after
{
 position: absolute;
 content: ' ';
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 right: -70px;
 top: 50%;
 border-width: 15px 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent #3184a1;
}

.menu-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 8px;
    z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="menu-icon" src="http://placehold.it/30x30"> 
<div class="navdiv">
  <div class="relative">
 <ul>
   <li>There's something here</li>
   <li>There's something here</li>
   <li>There's something here</li>
   <li>There's something here</li>
   <li>There's something here</li>
   <li>There's something here</li>
  </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```